# How to show JSON data into RecyclerView using adapter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-viewmodel

I have succeeded pulling JSON from Reddit API but I cannot put it into my RecyclerView. I set a Log to check if my JSON is empty or null, and the Log successfully print the desired output, so that means my JSON is not empty and contains the necessary data.

Here is my `PostRowAdapter.kt`

```
class PostRowAdapter(private val viewModel: MainViewModel)
    : ListAdapter<RedditPost, PostRowAdapter.VH>(RedditDiff()) {
    private var awwRow = listOf<RedditPost>()           

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        val binding = holder.binding
        awwRow[position].let{
            binding.title.text = it.title
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = awwRow.size
}
```

I thought my code was correct, but when I ran the app, the RecyclerView still blank. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `PostRowAdapter` is populating `awwRow` list, which is empty on start and never updated, thus this `RecyclerView` will always contain 0 elements

if you are using `ListAdapter` and `submitList(...)` method then you shouldn't override `getItemCount` and you shouldn't have own data list, so remove these lines

```
private var awwRow = listOf<RedditPost>() // on top

override fun getItemCount() = awwRow.size // on bottom
```

if you want access to whole list set with `submitList()` method then you can call inside adapter [`getCurrentList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#getCurrentList()). if you need a particular item at position (like in `onBindViewHolder`) then use [`getItem(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#getItem(int)). So instead of

```
 awwRow[position].let{
```

you should have

```
getItem(position).let{
```

Comment: if I erase awwRow, the awwRow[position] will get error. What should I add to avoid the error?

Comment: read my answer to the end, you should have `getItem(position)` in there. `awwRow` is useless, it is always empty and you are never adding any item to this list (`sumbitList` won't "automatically guess" that this is your "real" data list, not this one kept under the hood for you by `ListAdapter`)